# How can I get the value correctly with split?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mask

I'm trying to get the value entered by the user and whenever he changes this redeemed value is also changed, but when I put a small value: R$5.00
nothing happens,
is only accepting high value: 400.00 and the return an absurd 40,000.00.
When I try to put a small value, the following NaN error occurs

```
const {valueAmount, textDescription} = props.navigation.state.params;
  const amoutSplit = valueAmount.split('R$ ');
  const includComma = amoutSplit[1].split(',');
  const amout = Number(includComma[0] + includComma[1]);
```

```
<Text>{Filters.convertMoneyTextMask(amout)}
</Text>
```

the mask

```
const convertMoneyTextMask = (value) => {
  if (value) {
    const stringOnlyNumbers = `${Number(value).toFixed(2)}`.replace(/\D/g, '');
    if (!stringOnlyNumbers) {
      return 'R$ 0,00';
    }

    const {length} = stringOnlyNumbers;
    if (length === 1) {
      return value >= 0
        ? `R$ 0,0${stringOnlyNumbers}`
        : `R$ -0,0${stringOnlyNumbers}`;
    }
    if (length === 2) {
      return value >= 0
        ? `R$ 0,${stringOnlyNumbers}`
        : `R$ -0,${stringOnlyNumbers}`;
    }
    let moneyMask = '';

    for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      if (i === length - 2) {
        moneyMask = `,${stringOnlyNumbers[i]}${moneyMask}`;
      } else if (i < length - 5 && (i - length - 3) % 3 === 0) {
        moneyMask = `${stringOnlyNumbers[i]}.${moneyMask}`;
      } else {
        moneyMask = `${stringOnlyNumbers[i]}${moneyMask}`;
      }
    }

    return value >= 0 ? `R$ ${moneyMask}` : `R$ -${moneyMask}`;
  }
  return 'R$ 0,00';
};
```

Comment: is this line doing what you think it is?  `const {length} = stringOnlyNumbers;`?

Comment: Yes, is happening as planned

Comment: whenever the user types the value in the input and wants to change the idea and make this change, however when I type the value, what I said in the post occurs.

Comment: Please check in the debugger -- everything you say suggests that the length variable is never getting set correctly

Comment: For example add the line `console.log(length);` right after it is assigned

Comment: console.log return 3

Comment: does it always return

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating amoutSplit[1].split) :/